# How to read each character in a variable

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a program that will allow a user to input a string of numbers, then backup the directories corresponding to said numbers in the order that the user inputted. (I realize I can do this in many simpler ways, but I am doing this as a learning experience type thing.)

So far my way of doing this is to have if commands checking for every possible combination of 1-5 in up to 5 digit numbers. It first goes to the first number in the sequence then it goes to the second, so on and so forth until until it reaches the amount of inputted numbers, at which point it exits.

For example: If I wanted the number 324.

```
@echo off
echo What do you want to back up?
set /P a=""
:OptionSet1
set b=a
*all other numbers*
if /I "%a%" equ "324" goto 3
:OptionSet2
set b=b
*all other numbers*
if /I "%a%" equ "324" goto 2
:OptionSet3
set b=c
*all other numbers*
if /I "%a%" equ "324" goto 4
:Exit
exit
:2
echo Now I'm running 2
if /I "%b%" equ "a" goto OptionSet2
if /I "%b%" equ "b" goto OptionSet3
if /I "%b%" equ "e" goto Exit
:3
echo Now I'm running 3
if /I "%b%" equ "a" goto OptionSet2
if /I "%b%" equ "b" goto OptionSet3
if /I "%b%" equ "e" goto Exit
:4
echo Now I'm running 4
if /I "%b%" equ "a" goto OptionSet2
if /I "%b%" equ "b" goto OptionSet3
if /I "%b%" equ "e" goto Exit
```

So what I was wondering: is there a way to take the user input, and read what they typed letter by letter then act according to what the letter was?

For example, say I input the number 52421. I want to to read what the first number is, preform a goto command and run what ever is at the goto, then I want it to go back to read the second number, so on and so forth until it gets to the end of the inputted string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, but keep in mind, I am very new to this so please explain in depth as to what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mid String** - Extract a Substring by Position

Description:    Similar to the Mid function in VB a batch script can return a specified number of characters from any position inside a string by specifying a substring for an expansion given a position and length using :~ while expanding a variable content. The example here shows how to extract the parts of a date.

Script:

```
echo.Date   : %date%
echo.Weekday: %date:~0,3%
echo.Month  : %date:~4,2%
echo.Day    : %date:~7,2%
echo.Year   : %date:~10,4%
```

Output:

```
Date   : Sat 03/11/2006
Weekday: Sat
Month  : 03
Day    : 11
Year   : 2006
```

Taken from http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.MidString

Comment: So how do the numbers correspond to the position? Is the first number where to start and the second how many characters to the right to go?

Comment: Yes, and the first character starts at position 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use spaces as "number seperators" and pass the entire string to another batch file (or , in this case, itself, allowing it to use recursion):

```
@echo off
set argstring=%*
if "%argstring%" EQU "" goto :EOF

set thisarg=%1
REM do stuff with thisarg here
echo.thisarg


set argstring=%argstring:* =%
call thisfile.bat argstring
goto :EOF
```

start this file from the command line using `call thisfile.bat 3 4 5 1 9` and it will echo

```
3
4
5
1
9
```

(recursion is SO nice)

hope this helped